# bokeh axis limits fail when mixing x_range with y_range across multiple plots

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to visualize a high-dim point set `x` (here of dim (6 x 42)) in a series of 2D scatter plots (`x[1]` vs `x[2]` etc.) using bokeh.  [edit2] See [this](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/notebooks/visualizing-results_files/visualizing-results_15_1.png) nice example from scikit-opt as a reference.  When `x[1]` occurs in two plots it should interact with the same range and the plots should rescale simultaneously.  I have accomplished this, but I don't get it to scale correctly. Here's a minimal example: [edit2]

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.io
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting
bokeh.io.output_notebook()

# That's my fictional dataset
x = np.random.randn(6, 42)
x[2] *= 10

# Build the pairwise scatter plots
kw = dict(plot_width=165, plot_height=165)
# `ranges` stores the range in each dimension,
# used as both, x- and y-range depending on
# where the variable is.
figs, ranges = {}, {}
for r, row in enumerate(x):
    for c, col in enumerate(x):
        if r is not c:
            fig = bokeh.plotting.figure(
                x_range=ranges.get(c, None), y_range=ranges.get(r, None),
                **kw)
            fig.scatter(x=col, y=row)

            fig.xaxis.axis_label = f'Dim {c}'
            fig.yaxis.axis_label = f'Dim {r}'

            if c not in ranges:
                ranges[c] = fig.x_range

            if r not in ranges:
                ranges[r] = fig.y_range

            figs[f'{r}_{c}'] = fig
        else:
            break

# Setup the plotting layout
plots = [[]]
for r, row in enumerate(x):
    for c, col in enumerate(x):
        if r is not c:
            plots[-1].append(figs[f'{r}_{c}'])
        else:
            plots.append([])
            break

staircase = bokeh.layouts.gridplot(plots, **kw)
bokeh.plotting.show(staircase)
```

.. into an ipython notebook (>=py3.6), bokeh sets the scale for dim 1, and 2 correctly.  Then, it starts to set the scale for the following dimensions as in dim 2.   Notice that I scaled dim 2 10-fold to make this point.

Interactively, I can rescale the plot back to optimal settings.  However, I'd like to do that by default.  What options do I have *inside bokeh* to rescale?  I played a bit with `fig.xaxis.bounds`, but unsuccessfully.  Thanks for your help!

Epilogue:
Following @bigreddot's answer, I added the lines:

```
for i, X in enumerate(x):
    ranges[i].start = X.min()
    ranges[i].end = X.max()
```

to fix the starting ranges.  I still think that the behaviour is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

From your code and description I still can't quite tell what you are hoping to accomplish. [1] But I will state that the default `DataRange1d` ranges that plot's use automatically make space for all renderers, across all plots they are shared by. In this sense, I see exactly what I would expect when I run your code. If you want something different, there are two things you could control:

- `DataRange1d` has a `.renderers` property. If you only want the "auto" ranging to be over a subset of the renderers, then you can explicitly set this property to the list you want. Renderers are returned by the glyph functions, e.g. `fig.scatter`
- Don't use the "auto" ranges. You can also set the `x_range` and `y_range` yourself to be `Range1d` objects. These have `start` and `end` properties that you can set, and these will be the definite bounds of the range, e.g. `x-range=Range1d(0, 10)`

[1] The ranges are linked in what I would consider an odd way, and I can't tell if that is intended. But that is a result of your looping/python code and not Bokeh.

Comment: The ranges are linked so that each dimension has a unique range. If you change the x[1]-range it'll change everywhere where x[1] is shown.  I edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: It still seems odd to me that you are linking x ranges to y ranges (which is happening because you are not only using a single int and not distinguishing `r` and `c` in the `ranges` dict) Perhaps you can take a screen shot and annotate it with what you want? In any case the options I have listed above are whats available for controlling ranges more directly.

Comment: see for example [this](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/notebooks/visualizing-results_files/visualizing-results_15_1.png), from scikit-opt.  I think it's quite useful.  How do you visualize your 7D functions?

Comment: I can't say that I have ever had to do that. So, perhaps I have nothing further I can offer by way of assistance.

Comment: Though just to re-iterate: Pan your plots. When you change a plot's x axis by panning left and right, other plots move *up and down*. You have made the x range of one plot be the y-range of another. This is because of the way you have looped and stored ranges. I can't imagine a scenario were you want a plots x range to be a neighbor plot's y range. Thats what you've accomplished, but the image you linked does not answer if that is actually your intent or not.

Comment: Actually the image you link almost certainly indicates that you *don't* want them linked in the way that you have. Perhaps this example can provide inspiration: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/models/file/iris_splom.py

Comment: Sorry, let me elaborate:  Each column belongs to one variable.  let's look at the third i.e. `x[2]`.  This variable should be plotted against all others row by row.  It makes sense for `x[2]` to occupy the x-axis here.  In the next column, however, `x[3]` will occupy the x-axis.  Therefore, x[2] has to be plotted as 'y' here.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: I added now x- and y-labels to clarify what is what.  You'll see that even though surprising, the linking matches the same dimensions.  The problem is for example with the scatter 'Dim 3 vs Dim 4'.